# Regarding threads in Swing GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I want to make sure I understand something. Please confirm of this is true or not.

One I declare a thread, and run something inside it - everything from that point on is going to run inside that thread, unless I explicitly create a new thread. No matter how many classes and methods the code passes through - it will stay in the same thread.

For example, let's say I have an application that runs entirely inside one custom JFrame. If I want the entire application to run inside the same thread, I can do this by creating a new thread, and instantiating the new JFrame inside the run() method of that thread.

Will this actually ensure that the entire application will run inside that thread where the JFrame was created, unless I explicitly create a new thread and run something inside that new thread?

This is a general question, but let me talk about Swing specifically for a second:

If I want the entire Swing application to run inside the EDT (which - and **please correct me if I'm wrong** - is exactly what I need most of the time with Swing), it's enough to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` once in the `main` method, like so:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
         JFrame frame = new CustomJFrame(); // where the entire application runs.
    } );
}
```

Comment: Except what Andrew just described, all the code in the listeners (`actionPerformed`, etc.) is executed in the EDT too.

Comment: @JiriKremser  Sorry, I deleted my comment because I had not read enough of the question before making it.  Good point re. the listeners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> One I declare a thread, and run something inside it - everything from
>   that point on is going to run inside that thread, unless I explicitly
>   create a new thread. No matter how many classes and methods the code
>   passes through - it will stay in the same thread.

Correct. In fact even if you create a new thread, current thread execution flow will never be changed. This new thread will start executing some time in the future after you started it, but its flow is independent from the thread that created it.

> which - and please correct me if I'm wrong - is exactly what I need
>   most of the time with Swing

You're wrong. You don't want to do everything in the EDT. Any data fetching and manipulation in the EDT will degrade your GUI reponsiveness. Say for example you want to fetch a lot of data from a DB. If you do so in the EDT, your GUI will freeze and the user will not be able to interact with it until you finish getting it (and probably manipulating it).

Comment: See also [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: I see. Other than tasks that take long to compelete - are there anymore kinds of tasks I should pay attention to not performing inside the EDT?

Comment: You should only use the EDT to update the GUI. Everything else should not be on the EDT. See Andrew Thompson's link above for more information.

Comment: Lets say I have a game written using Swing. Most of the game logic runs in the custom JPanel class, that also displays the game. This class updates the GUI frequently, but also manipulates variables and makes calculations very often, like done in games. Does that mean that every other line of code I need to use invokeLater() or create a new thread?

Comment: *"Everything else should not be on EDT."*  I disagree with going that far.  E.G. a calculator app. would typically do the calculations on the EDT immediately before displaying them in a label or text field (also on the EDT).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Could you answer the question I presented in my last comment please? As you said, it seems unreasonable to me to only perform inside the EDT tasks that manipulate the GUI. Games manipulate the GUI **and** perform calculations all of the time. I don't think it makes sense to constantly switch threads when doing so.

Comment: @Prog *"manipulates variables and makes calculations very often, like done in games"*  So long as they are not **long running** calculations, I would do them on the EDT.  For finding the factors of a 27 digit number, shift them off the EDT into a `SwingWorker`.  The underlying question is.  If the GUI did not respond from when the calcs. start, to when they finish, would the user even notice?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Notice *"should"* and not *"must"*.

Comment: @Prog Depends on how heavy the calculations are and how often you want to refresh. Consider that the human eye can only distinguish around 60 FPS, so it's no use to update faster than that.

Comment: *"Notice "should" and not "must""*  Good point.  I was thinking you meant the latter.

Comment: @AndrewThompson and m0skit0 - do you have some experience in making games with Swing? If so, is it common for games written using Swing to run almost entierly on the EDT? Or do game applications use a different approach then clicking-buttons and filling-text-fields kind of applications?

Comment: *"do you have some experience in making games with Swing?"*  Games no.   But I do have experience with animations.  One that might be close to the same as a game was a 'zooming star field'.  It involved stars coming towards the viewer.  Each position and 'trail length' for each of 800+ stars needed to be calculated for each frame.  Those calculations were done **on** the EDT.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still not sure about the answer to my first question: When starting to run something a thread, any code that it leads to, no matter how many classes it goes through and how many method calls there are, it will stay on the same thread, unless I create a new one. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer to answer that too. *"unless I create a new one"* Even if you create a new one, your current thread will not change.